# Python app using FLASK : The requested URL was not found on the server

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to test a simple TODO APP using a REST API with Flask. I'm using curl to send a POST request and test out my app. The goal is to be able to write a new note without needing a front-end web UI.

```
curl -X POST http://127.0.0.1:5000/item -d '{"item": "Setting up Flask"}' -H 'Content-Type: application/json'
```

But I'm getting the error

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>404 Not Found</title>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.</p>
```

Here's my code

```
import helper
from flask import Flask, request, Response
import json

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
   return 'Hello World!'

@app.route('/item/new', methods = ['POST'])
def add_item():
   
   req_data = request.get_json()
   item = req_data['item']
   
   #Add item to the list
   res_data = helper.add_to_list(item)

   
   if res_data is None:
      response = Response("{'error': 'Item not added - '}"  + item, status=400 , mimetype='application/json')
      return response
   
   
   response = Response(json.dumps(res_data), mimetype='application/json')
   
   return response
```

and here's the helper file

```
import sqlite3

DB_PATH = './todo.db'
NOTSTARTED = 'Not Started'
INPROGRESS = 'In Progress'
COMPLETED = 'Completed'

def add_to_list(item):
    try:
        conn = sqlite3.connect(DB_PATH)
        c = conn.cursor()
        c.execute('insert into items(item, status) values(?,?)', (item, NOTSTARTED))
        conn.commit()
        return {"item": item, "status": NOTSTARTED}
    except Exception as e:
        print('Error: ', e)
        return None
```

Comment: These two routes do not match: `@app.route('/item/new')` and `http://127.0.0.1:5000/item`. Have you tried changing the cURL url to `http://127.0.0.1:5000/item/new` ?

Comment: Yeah it seems when I do that I get an error that the item wasn't added

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your route is wrong. You are sending to /item when you define your route as /route/new. Try changing it to this:

```
curl -X POST http://127.0.0.1:5000/item/new -d '{"item": "Setting up Flask"}' -H 'Content-Type: application/json'
```